# What's the best way to make this less dumb?

Tags: javascript

I'm a javascript begginer, and this don't feel good at all.

```
function crapFunction() {
    if (var.search('abc') > -1) {
       var word = 'agr4b';
    } else if (var.search('dfc') > -1) {
       var word = 'gr42';
    } else if (var.search('ant') > -1) {
       var word = 'bt5';
    } else if (var.search('her') > -1) {
       var word = '4f4f';
    } 
};
```

Comment: By using case or using ternary?

Comment: `var` should not be used as a variable name

Comment: And what problem is this attempt meant to be solving?

Comment: Don't post a meaningless made-up example. We can't help you with that. Post your real code.

Comment: Mr. Alien, Bhojendra: thanks, will try that. David: define a variable by detecting a specific string on another one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Could you please clarify what you are trying to accomplish (e.g. do you want a "cleaner" version of this function?  I am sorry your first experience was rough here, and am hoping you have better ones!  I'd suggest checking out the site tour (under help).  It has good information about this site, and you get a badge :-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for code review.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to do a better version of that, with less lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
function crapFunction(str) {
    var word = false;
    switch(str) {
        case 'abc':
            word = 'agr4b';
            break;
        case 'dfc':
            word = 'gr42';
            break;
    }
    return word;
}
```